# Timestamp parsing from string with microseconds precision on pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I need to parse from a spark column with string data type a timestamp in the following format:
2023-11-17T08:28:40.71910 +01:00

when i try to convert it through

```
df.withColumn("timestamp", f.to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS Z"))
```

it returns null.

how can i handle this to obtain a unix timestamp with decimal values representing microseconds values?

Answer (score 0):

The fractional seconds in your timestamp (".71910") have five digits. Spark expects up to three digits for fractional seconds (milliseconds). Having more than three digits can cause a parsing error.

Here's modified code which works.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import dateutil.parser



sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

data1 = [["2023-11-17T08:28:40.71910 +01:00"]]

df1Columns = ["ts"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)

new_df = df1.withColumn("adjusted_ts", F.regexp_replace("ts", "(\\.[0-9]{3})[0-9]*", "$1"))
new_df = new_df.withColumn("converted_ts", F.to_timestamp(F.col("adjusted_ts"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS XXX"))
new_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+
|ts                              |adjusted_ts                   |converted_ts           |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+
|2023-11-17T08:28:40.71910 +01:00|2023-11-17T08:28:40.719 +01:00|2023-11-17 12:58:40.719|
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+
```